# How To redirect to home page after login with google using firebase in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to redirect to home page after login with google and facebook using firebase in ionic3.

When user click google icons or facebook icons, then they redirect to the ionic app and go to `home.html` page

Redirecting from google or facebook to ionic app is working well and it shows login page, But I want to show `home.html` page

Here I share my codes

`login.ts`

**Facebook login**

```
        loginfb() {
       this.facebook.login(['email']).then((response) => {
      const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
        .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);

    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
        .then((success) => {
            console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
            this.userProfile = success;
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });

}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
});
}
```

**Google login**

```
 logingoogle() {
  this.googlePlus.login({
      'webClientId': 'xxxxx',
      'offline': true
  }).then(res => {
      firebase.auth()
          .signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
          .then(success => {
              console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
              this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
          })
          .catch(error => console.log("Firebase failure: " +
              JSON.stringify(error)));
  }).catch(err => console.error("Error: ", err));
  }
```

Comment: Did you know answer for this? @Utpaul

Comment: try this
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);  or
this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(HomePage);

Comment: where to add?? after the success line?

Comment: yes in succes fn you have to use